# Splice an Array rendered with DOM by clicking button (Vanilla Js)

Tags: javascript

Once myLibrary is rendered I need to .splice() a book once his delete button is pressed. I tried this but didn't work. It says deleteBtn is null.

```
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delete-button')
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', ...)
```

Here's how myLibrary is rendered.

```js
function renderMyLibrary() {
    library.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
        const book = document.createElement('div');
        book.classList.add('book');
        book.setAttribute('id', i);
        const newTitle = document.createElement('div');
        newTitle.textContent = `${myLibrary[i].title}`;
        const newAuthor = document.createElement('div');
        newAuthor.textContent = `${myLibrary[i].author}`;
        const newPages = document.createElement('div');
        newPages.textContent = `${myLibrary[i].pages}`;
        const deleteButton = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        deleteButton.classList.add('delete-button');
        deleteButton.textContent = `delete`;
        book.append(newTitle);
        book.append(newAuthor);
        book.append(newPages);
        book.append(deleteButton);
        library.append(book);
    }
}
```

Comment: What code did you try for your click button? Add a `console.log()` to it to ensure it is actually getting called in the first place.

Comment: Can you sare more of your code? I think you're basically trying to capture the delete-buttons before they are rendered by your renderMyLibrary function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation for dynamically added elements, much easy and cleaner.

See below how we use a `matches` to determine what is clicked.

```js
const getContainer = () => document.querySelector('.sample');

const addMore = () => {
  const container = getContainer();
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const text = Date.now();
    div.innerHTML = `Sample ${i}`;
    div.id = text;
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  if(target.matches('button')) {
    addMore();
  }
  
  if(target.matches('div')) {
    getContainer().removeChild(target);
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="sample">

</div>

<button>Add More</button>
```

Lets build on the code and have delete buttons, rather than elements.

```js
const getContainer = () => document.querySelector('.sample');

const addMore = () => {
  const container = getContainer();
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const text = Date.now();
    div.innerHTML = `Sample ${i}`;
    div.id = text;
    container.appendChild(div);
    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerText = 'Delete';
    btn.classList.add('delete');
    btn.dataset.for = text;
    container.appendChild(btn);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  if(target.matches('.addMore')) {
    addMore();
  }
  
  if(target.matches('.delete')) {
    const delElement = document.querySelector(`div[id='${target.dataset.for}']`);
    getContainer().removeChild(delElement);
    getContainer().removeChild(target);
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="sample">

</div>

<button class="addMore">Add More</button>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the event delegation concept nor "matches". Of course I couldn't do it, I was trying to add an event listener to an html element that is not in the original HTML but in the DOM. I'll try this. Thanks !